# read the file that is opened with my console application in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, fstream, ifstream

I have written a console application in C++ and I need to read the file that is opened with my console app:

- right click on `txt` file
- select `open with`
- choose my console application

---

then I want to read that `.txt` file. how?

[my source code](https://github.com/MohammadMD1383/ConsoleAppCPP)

Comment: I assuming you want this for a Windows environment. Then you need to register your program in the correct way. There are probably plenty of tutorials on how to do this if you just search a little.

Comment: Consider using [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [FLTK](http://fltk.org/). A software which handles mouse clicks is *not*  a console application, but a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm new and I don't know what topic should I search. could you please tell me what should I search for?

Comment: Perhaps something like `add to "open with" in windows`?

Comment: You can do excatly what you stated there, right click, open with, choose your program. At least in windows 10 you can pick an arbitrary program to open that file. Not sure about other versions of windows.

Comment: thanks to all comments. but nobody told me how to read that file in cpp?

Comment: You just need to declare arguments to your main like this: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);` and the file path will be passed as one of the argument. If you open multiple files, it will run one process per file.

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you very much. this was the answer I was looking for.♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare arguments to your [main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-160) like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ...
}
```

And the file path will be passed as one of the argument. If you open multiple files, it will run one process per file.